# How can I convince TeX to add space around math operators?

Tags: spacing, math-operators

Since when is *this* good typesetting?

[image: scrunched union operator]

What's the best way to make TeX typeset all three like the bottom one?  Do I need to resort to a new command that outputs `{\ \cup\ }`?  That would seem to fly in the face of the whole ``TeX knows best'' philosophy, which this example seems to contradict.  That non-spacing is hugely and ridiculously *not OK!*  (The input is—you guessed it—`$\mathcal{S}\cup\mathcal{E}$`.)

=====================

Per David Carlisle's answer I changed `minus 4mu` to `minus 2mu` in the value of `\medmuskip` and got the improved result below, which I consider acceptable.

[image]

Comment: You should provide a test file so that people can see the issue and test answers but presumably you have specified that `\medmuskip` has stretch and shrink, and TeX has had to shrink it here. But it is a user setable length, so it's just doing what is specified by the user.

Comment: the default value is very shrinkable `\medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu`

Comment: The string `medmuskip' appears nowhere in the directory the input file resides in, though the input (LaTeX) file does load a bunch of packages.  According to your second comment my guess is that the spacing choice is just what TeX defaults to.  Your comments have showed me the proper way to get what I want - I figured there was some parameter to adjust but didn't know what it was.  Thank you!

Comment: Most authors try to cram as much text into a given space as possible.  Artistic typesetting is for people like e.e. cummings.

Comment: @JohnKormylo most authors are into crappy typesetting?  News to me.

Comment: Nah, fnord is crappy typesetting ;-)  (Illuminatus Trilogy)

Comment: This isn't code-related, but is the output really bad as per the standard conventions? (Asks a non-mathematician and a complete newbie in typesetting) If it is really bad, then why not to report and fix it instead of just ridiculing TeX? It might benefit a lot of users. _To the questioner: one can always make TeX better and eventually the best unlike many other non-free software ;-)_

Comment: Not really related to the substance of the question - your tone is very obnoxious, and does not encourage people to help you (for free) to use your (also free) software. Your question would be significantly improved by removing all text except the problem statement.

Comment: Note that the `\medmuskip` is also used in some other places, so if you change it, you might get unexpected changes elsewhere.

Comment: @mickep that said, but the default of allowing medmuskip to shrink to be less than thinmuskip and in fact be 0mu is hard to justify in many ways other than no one daring to challenge Knuth's defaults. (what does context do?)

Comment: I don't know if it makes sense to let `\medmuskip` shrink to 0, but I'm sure there is some thought behind it. ConTeXt uses the same values (per default, with addition of \tinumuskip which I think is just 1mu,), but it has recently opened up so that you can use whatever you want between whatever atoms you want, including defining your own (there are also more atom classes now, one for fractions, one for radicals, one for differentials, one for the factorial, ...).

Comment: I would love to hear Knuth's reason for choosing minus 4mu as the default value.  We can rest assured he had one and that it was a good one.  Maybe he would regard those scrunched-together unions differently than I do.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The space around `\binop` is `\medmuskip` and LaTeX follows plain TeX in giving this a value with a large shrink component

```
\medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
```

You could change this value to get different effects.

Comment: Changing the 'minus 4mu' to 'minus 2mu' fixed the problem.  I added the resulting output to the question.